# Concatinate top 5 results in one column

Tags: sql, string-aggregation

I have a table  that gives me the following output.

[image]

I want to write a query that gives me the result of the top 5 rows fetched from the above table (just col2) and then display them in just one column as comma separated.

Basically what I want the output as:
[image]

Can you give me the sql query for the same.

Comment: Which database server are you using? Some like MySQL have functions like group_concat() that can turn values from several rows into one comma separated string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-aggregation+sql

Answer (score 1):

If your DB is MySQL, use:

```
select group_concat(col2 separator ', ') as str from myTable;
```

If your DB is Oracle, use:

```
select listagg(col2, ', ') within group (order by col1) as str from myTable;
```

If your DB is Postgres, use:

```
select string_agg(col2, ',' order by col1) as str from mytable;
```